# How to view notices when testing?

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a class that issues a non-fatal notice:

```
class MyClass {
    public function foo(){
        trigger_error('Notice this message.', E_USER_NOTICE);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here's a basic unit test:

```
class MyClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testCanFoo(){
        $obj = new MyClass;
        $this->assertTrue($obj->foo());
    }
}
```

Naturally PHPUnit converts this notice into an exception, which uncaught necessarily fails the test as an error.

> There was 1 error:
>
> 1) MyClassTest::testCanFoo
>   Notice this message.

Firstly, let me point out that I love that I can read this notice, and ***this*** is what I want, **but** without failing the test.

I know I can get the test to pass with a [docblock](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.errors).

```
class MyClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    /**
     *  @expectedException PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Notice
     */
    public function testCanFoo(){
        $obj = new MyClass;
        $this->assertTrue($obj->foo());
    }
}
```

But now the notice is completely swallowed up.

> PHPUnit 5.5.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> .                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)
>
> Time: 17 ms, Memory: 4.00MB
>
> OK (1 test, 1 assertion)

How can I get it to *both* pass the test **and** view the notice message?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412746/ignoring-the-php-warnings-in-phpunit) looks like it has some useful info on this.

Comment: Thanks @Don'tPanic I did actually come across that question, but both are suppression alternatives to my docblock solution.

Comment: Ah, I see. I wasn't sure if not converting them to exceptions would prevent them from displaying or not.

Comment: @Don'tPanic actually, that answer is what I needed after all, thank you. I'm not sure how I missed it on the first pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the conversion into exception in this manner:

```
class MyClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testCanFoo(){
        // disable conversion into exception
        PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Notice::$enabled = false;
        $obj = new MyClass;
        $this->assertTrue($obj->foo());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm not sure how I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Netsilik/BaseTestCase](https://github.com/Netsilik/BaseTestCase) (MIT License) you can test directly for triggered Errors/Warnings, without converting them to Exceptions.

You can test both for the correct Waring/Notice type as well as the error message:

`composer require netsilik/base-test-case`

Testing for an `E_USER_NOTICE`:

```
<?php
namespace Tests;

class MyTestCase extends \Netsilik\Testing\BaseTestCase
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function __construct($name = null, array $data = [], $dataName = '')
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $data, $dataName);

        $this->_convertNoticesToExceptions  = false;
        $this->_convertWarningsToExceptions = false;
        $this->_convertErrorsToExceptions   = true;
    }

    public function test_whenNoticeTriggered_weCanTestForIt()
    {
        $foo = new Foo();
        $foo->bar();

        self::assertErrorTriggered(E_USER_NOTICE, 'The notice string');
    }
}
```

Cheers.