# How do I run phpunit test despite tested code throwing Notices

Tags: php, phpunit

I know ideally that I should fix all the places in my code where PHP Notices are being thrown but for now I am trying to get a simple test up and running for one part of the application.

When I try to run my test using

```
sudo phpunit -c tests/phpunit.xml tests/
```

I get the following notices:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$integer_value in /var/www/application/authenticate.php on line 111
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$boolean_value in /var/www/application/authenticate.php on line 115
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$boolean_value in /var/www/application/site/authenticate.php on line 115
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$integer_value in /var/www/application/authenticate.php on line 111
```

I've tried following the advice on this answer to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/8412996/3263538

and have created a phpunit.xml configuration file which includes the following xml to ignore notices and warnings

**tests/phpunit.xml**

```
<phpunit convertErrorsToExceptions="false"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="false"
         convertWarningEToExceptions="false">
</phpunit>
```

**UtilitesTest.php** (dummy test that returns true)

```
<?php
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

include_once "/var/www/application/utilities.php";

class UtilitiesTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testEmpty()
    {
        return 1;
    }

}
?>
```

but still no luck. Is there something I'm missing here? Ideally I'd like to suppress these Notice messages.

Comment: There are a lot more all over the place...These are just a few.

Comment: Could you post the code for ```/var/www/application/authenticate.php``` from Line 111 to Line 116 ?