# PHPUnit - I get some unecessary exception (undefined variable)

Tags: php, cmd, phpunit, testcase

I'm started to use PHPUnit, and I want to connect to my database and get some values from it, but as I have to connect to my database through the file 'database.php'.

'database.php' always had this problem with the undefined variable: $connected.
So I read something about with the error-reporting message: error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

I did fix it earlier to my other files in my Project, but when I use PHPUnit I get this error message: Undefined variable: connected

My testcase file and it's code:

```
<?php include("database.php"); ?>
<?php
require_once 'person.php';

class PersonTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function lookupPerson(){

    $result = database::query("select * from Person where forename='Anna'");
    $rows = mysql_numrows($result);
    for($i=0; $i < $rows; $i++){
    $arr[$i] = mysql_result($result, $i, 'forename');
    }
    return $arr;
    }


    public function testLooking(){
    $arr = PersonTest::lookupPerson();
    foreach($arr as $a){
    $this->assertEquals('Anna', $a);
    }
    }
}


?>
```

So I wonder what can I do?

Regards
User

also
Alexein

Comment: Is this your real test? You don't actually test anything in the Person class, just a method in the test class?

Answer (score 1):

At the top of your code add below, this hides all notices... Ofcourse its best to just fix the error :)

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set("display_errors", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this question: [test the return value of a method that triggers an error with PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225776/test-the-return-value-of-a-method-that-triggers-an-error-with-phpunit)

answers there show how to prevent PHPUnit from treating notices and warnings as exceptions.

if you can, fix the notice.

Answer (score 0):

> I did fix it earlier to my other files in my Project, but when I use PHPUnit I get this error message: Undefined variable: connected

From what line in `database.php` is this notice being thrown? Perhaps you do a `if (!$connected)` somewhere, while `$connected` never has been written to. So begin your `database.php` with `$connected = false` and you'll lose the notice.