# Convert Simpletest test suite to PHPUnit

Tags: phpunit, migrate, simpletest

I use Simpletest test suites to run all tests, with different configuration methods. I've created one suite per config method, and it sets up the environment and then runs all tests.

Take a look at [Adapter.php](https://github.com/Znarkus/postmark-php/blob/master/Tests/Adapter.php) and [Constants.php](https://github.com/Znarkus/postmark-php/blob/master/Tests/Constants.php) if that's unclear.

Now there seems to be [support for test suites in PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/organizing-tests.html#organizing-tests.xml-configuration), but as I understand it, it's merely for grouping tests with no support for setting up the environment or running PHP scripts.

How can I convert my test suites to PHPUnit? I'm open to rethink how the tests are structured :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use test fixtures to setup your environment either before each test, or before each test suite:

http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/fixtures.html#fixtures.more-setup-than-teardown

The methods you are looking for are

- `setUp()` and `tearDown()` (called before/after each single test), and
- `setUpBeforeClass()` and `tearDownAfterClass()` (called before/after each test class (suite)).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from restructuring your test suite you should also be aware that the behaviour of the `assertions` in PHPUnit is different from SimpleTest.

While in SimpleTest you can test on an assertions result and execute further code after a failed assertion, you cannot in PHPUnit: [test the return value of a method that triggers an error with PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225776/test-the-return-value-of-a-method-that-triggers-an-error-with-phpunit)

This will likely also force refactoring some of the actual tests.